# CodeIgniter 3 - IonAuth, controller and method instead of route

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I have problem with my app.
I have login page and I set route:

```
$route['logowanie'] = 'Back/index/Login';
```

But when I get error on login, my address set:
    ***mydomain.com/Back/index/Login***
but I want to stay on my route - ***mydomain.com/logowanie***.

Where is problem? I using IonAuth library

Comment: If you have Back.php then you will only need index() method which fetches the login view.

Comment: You have to change code in IonAuth's code/method.

Comment: logowanie.php must have index.php that fetches the login view.

Answer (score 0):

In your controllers `function login()` change to:

```
//if the login was un-successful
//redirect them back to the login page
$this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
redirect('logowanie', 'refresh');
```